# Do apps like iMyFone LockWiper actually work?

Tags: security, lock-screens, encryption, anti-theft

I recently had my phone stolen and would like to know if I should change all my debit cards and other sensitive info. I want to know if is it possible to actually **bypass the default lock screen and password** for Android on a [Samsung Galaxy J7 Pro](https://www.gizmochina.com/product/samsung-galaxy-j7-pro/). I am running Android version 12 and **do not have developer mode enabled.**

Apps like [iMyFone and LockWiper](https://itoolab.com/unlock-android/imyfone-lockwiper-android-review-and-alternative/) claim that they can do this. If so how? I thought, **your data was encrypted if you use a password.**

Comment: The phone data is encrypted but the OS will automatically decrypt it once you have entered the lockscreen secret the first time after boot. And there was just recently a serious flaw found in the lockscreen which allows to bypass it: https://www.androidpolice.com/one-minute-hack-allowed-lock-screen-bypass-on-android-current-pixels-are-safe/ (not sure if this also applies to our phone) BTW: Why do you store debit card info on your phone?

Comment: Without knowing how those apps work, we have a related tag [tag:locked-out] for end-users who want to bypass/remove the lock screen. Combined with the ['lock-screens'](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blocked-out%5D+%5Block-screens%5D+answers%3A1) tag, you might be interested in browsing them.

Comment: @Robert What if the lockscreen secret is not known to the attacker ? Is there any chance the attacker can access the data ?

Comment: @Robert How are you able to access the `/data` partition without decryption ? Look at this article. https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/remove-bypass-lockscreen-with-recovery.3530008/page-10

Comment: As I wrote once you have entered the lock screen password the first time after boot all data can be decrypted until you reboot. So if there is a way to bypass lock screen without rebooting the data can be accessed decrypted. Such a way to bypass lock screen was described in the linked article of my first comment.

Comment: @Robert Thats with a SIM card switch, but to flash TWRP and then access the `/data` partition the phone must rebooted at least once correct ?

Comment: Flashing TWRP means the bootloader is already unlocked (because unlocking it erases user data), in such cases the common assumption is that the phone security is broken even if you still need the lock screen password to access the user data via TWRP. Broken means you should not rely on it.

Comment: @Robert So is it safe to say that if the boot loader is not unlocked, and the phone is rebooted, the `/data` partition should not be readable as its encrypted right ?

Comment: Yes, unless you have a very dumb lock screen password that can be guessed in a few dozen tries.